# .position() dando erro - JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou recebendo o seguinte erro:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: position is not defined
```

O que tem de errado no código?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.main_menu a').click(function () {
        var g = '.' + $(this).attr('href').replace('#','') + position.top;
        console.log(g);
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você não definiu a variável: position

Veja o exemplo retirado do site jquery

```
<script>
    var p = $( "p:first" );
    var position = p.position();
    $( "p:last" ).text( "left: " + position.left + ", top: " + position.top );
</script>
```